# UIwebview initially loaded zoomly?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, uiwebviewdelegate

Hi i am new to iOS development. I have uiwebview for load a website. What is my problem is when the website load 1st time in the uiwebview the page show zoomly. Then when click other page inside or refresh the same page its comes under normal responsive page. I want initially the page should be normal or responsive page.. Can any one help me. Thanks in advance

[image: This is image represent when i entered in web view the page will be zoom like this image]
[image: After refresh a view the page will be in normal or responsive image]

Comment: try this webView.scalesPageToFit = NO;

Comment: where can i put this code @ T_77

Comment: anywhere you wish. try in viewdidload or the method where you call the load request for your webview

Comment: Sorry @T_77 now also i getting same zooming initial page.. i want without zooming

Comment: can  u please post the screenshot?

Comment: wait T_77.. with in 2 min i come with screenshot

Comment: Real image: ![file:///Users/EmployeeLogin/Desktop/Real%20Page.png]

Comment: Zooming image : ![file:///Users/EmployeeLogin/Desktop/Zoomingpage.PNG]

Comment: kindly fix this image URL to clarify your doubts. And give me the some idea for me

Comment: we can t see the image. It it in your machine.

Comment: sorry for the inconvenience. some problem i can't send photo today.. i will post you tomorrow . sorry for that...@T_77

Comment: Thanks for your information